# Pythonでのデータ収集環境について、自分の解釈が正しいかどうか

Tags: python, anaconda, web-scraping

Pythonでwebスクレイピングがしたいと思い、いろいろと調べていました。
自分の状態としては、Pythonについては一通り勉強が終わっている（はずの）状態です。

①AnacondaはPythonの機能を拡張するために用意されているもので、インストールすることで、webからデータを集めるためにコンパイルされたコードがあらかじめ用意されている。

②Anacondaをインストールしておくと、必要に応じてPythonのIDEからimportで呼び出すことができる。
（IDEにはPyCharmを用いる予定ですが、何か別途設定は必要ですか？という趣旨）

③スクレイピングをする際に、仮想環境を用いると書いているところがあったが、個人的に用いるなら特に必要はない？

以上３つが質問です。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3):

① Anacondaは、自ら`Python Data Science Distribution`と名乗っているように、データサイエンスを中心にPythonを使う場合はいい選択肢になります。逆にWebアプリケーションを作る場合には、関連するパッケージが不足するので`pip`でインストールすることが多くなり管理が難しくなります。webスクレイピングをするぐらいでアプリケーションまで作らないのであれば、Anacondaはベターな選択だと思います。質問にも書いてあるように事前にコンパイルされているのでインストールも楽です。

② PyCharmの場合は、Anacondaに対応しているので自動で認識してくれる場合が多いです。もし、自動で認識してくれない場合は、メニューから`File->Settings->Project Interpreter`で、使用するPythonを設定できるようになっています。

③ データサイエンスを中心に使っている場合は、直ぐには仮想環境が必要になるケースは少ないと思います。コードの量が非常に多くなってPythonやパッケージのアップデートに総てのコードを追従できなくなった場合やAnacondaのパッケージで不足して`pip`でパッケージをインストールするようになると、そのプロジェクトには仮想環境を作って環境を分けておいた方がいいので、その時点で仮想環境を使うことを検討したらいいと思います。

なお、Mac、Linuxで使う場合は、既にPythonがインストールされているので、Anacondaをインストールする時にパスを通さずに、次のようにしてAnacondaの環境を使う前に起動した方が安全です。

```
source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate
```

これを毎回入力するのが面倒な場合はエイリアスに登録するといいです。次のようにすると`myconda`で環境を起動できます。

```
alias myconda="source $HOME/anaconda3/bin/activate"
```

Comment: +1。ただし、データサイエンスを中心に行う場合でも、Python 2 / 3 問題のせいで conda create することは私は割とあります。

Comment: NumPyは、2019年1月以降の新規リリースからPython3対応版のみになります。今から始めるのであれば、Python2は過去の話でいいのではないかと思います。ただし、受託で仕事をする場合は必要かもしれませんが。。。