# Anacondaのpythonにパスを通してよいか？ pipでなくcondaを使っていてよいか？

Tags: python, python3, anaconda

[以前の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/46890/3054)へいただいた回答に、

> なお、Mac、Linuxで使う場合は、既にPythonがインストールされているので、Anacondaをインストールする時にパスを通さずに、次のようにしてAnacondaの環境を使う前に起動した方が安全です。

- ①とありましたが、Windowsで使用するのであれば、Anacondaをインストールする際にソフト側にパスを通してもらっても問題ないでしょうか？
- ②また、現在Python3.6を使っているので、pipが同梱されています。
  pipとcondaを一緒に使わないほうがよいという記事を見たのですが、見る限り（のちに仮想環境が必要になったときなどに）condaのほうが使いやすいような気がしたので、
  とりあえずcondaを使っていればいいのでしょうか？

使用する環境は、Windows10,64bitです。

Comment: 自分の質問に対してはコメントを行うことが出来ます。別のアカウントでログインしている場合、また、前のアカウントが分からなくなってしまった場合は[アカウントをマージ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)を見てください。

Comment: 「この質問の回答はすでにここにあります」として重複でクローズになっていますが、これは別の質問です。一つの投稿に次々と質問を追加していくのは、スタック・オーバーフローの使い方として推奨されるものではありません。質問者さんが新たな質問として投稿されたことで、結果的により回答が寄せやすくなっており、クローズする理由は無いと思います。再オープンに投票いたしました。（別の話として、Myakuさんが指摘されているようにアカウントのマージは行った方がよいでしょう）

Comment: @mjy 回答へのコメント～で先走りすぎました。読み直してみてただのコメントではなく回答から別の質問に派生しているように見えたので再オープンしました。

Answer (score 4):

① Windowsの場合は問題ありません。
linuxの場合、`anaconda3/bin`というディレクトリーには、Pythonを始めとして多くに実行ファイルが含まれています。そこにパスを通すことにより、システムにインストールされている実行ファイルよりも`anaconda3/bin`にある実行ファイルが優先して使われるようになるというのがトラブルの原因です。しかし、Windowsの場合、アプリケーションは`.NET Framework`又は`Win32 API`を使うのが基本になっているので、`anaconda3`等にパスを通したとしても影響は限定的です。

② Anacondaを使う場合は、パッケージをインストールする場合`conda`を使うのが基本です。しかしながら、Anacondaにすべてのパッケージが用意されているわけではないので、Anacondaには存在しない場合に`pip`を使います。

pipとcondaを一緒に使わないほうがよいという記事は、[condaとpip：混ぜるな危険](http://onoz000.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/02/11/142347)という記事だと思います。注意は必要なのですがあまり神経質になる必要はないと思います。

その記事の例であがっている`PyQT`はデスクトップアプリケーション作成用のパッケージで、そもそも`Anaconda`が対象としているものではなく普通は`Anaconda`を使うようなものではありません。データサイエンスを中心に`Python`を使う場合には、「Anaconda環境下でpipを使う場合のリスクについて、日本語で書かれたページがほとんど見つからなかった」とその記事に書かれているように、`pip`が必要になるというのはたまで問題がないケースが多いです。

なお、「現在Python3.6を使っているので、pipが同梱されています」と書いてありますが、`Anaconda`にもpipが同梱されています。`Anaconda`にパスをとおすと、`pip`と打った場合、`Anaconda`の`pip`が動作して、`Anaconda`の環境にパッケージがインストールされるようになります。

Comment: つまり、仮想環境内にインストールされたpipを使用してパッケージをダウンロードするのは問題ないという事でしょうか？その場合、パッケージはroot環境と分離されてインストールされているのでしょうか？